# Apache http server rewrite or redirect

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a functioning environment with an apache http server (load  balancer) with a cluster of tomcat servers at the back end.  I am stumped by one problem though, I am not able to redirect or rewrite the request url to what I need. for example,

```
request url - http://www.yyy.com
```

i would like to redirect or rewrite it to

```
http://www.yyy.com/mycontext
```

I tried redirect and rewrite with no luck.

```
RewriteRule    ^/$  http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/  [L] - Error (can't fine the url)
```

AND then I tried this,

```
Redirect / http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/ - this results in the following, 

http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/mycontext/mycontext/mycontext/mycontext/........... repeats.
```

I am not able to figure out the right condition statement.  I tried using the server variables to write a rewritecond but I am doing something wrong and it gets ignored.

Any assistance is appreciated.  I have not had much experience in this area.

Comment: Can you show your reverse proxy/load balancer directives?

Comment: I tried using a proxypass as follows: ProxyPass / http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/  and that got me an error - Server ran out of threads to serve requests. Consider raising the ThreadsPerChild setting.  So I started experimenting with redirect and rewrites

Comment: And this `ProxyPass / http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/` is in the config for `www.yyy.com`?

Comment: yes in the virtualhost. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> And this **`ProxyPass / http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/`** is in the config for **www.yyy.com**?

> yes in the virtualhost

Not sure how your load balancer could ever possibly work. You are proxying requests back to yourself, and it's going to instantly run out of threads because each proxied request runs on its own thread.

1. Request for `/` arrives at your virtual host
2. `ProxyPass` reverse proxies it to `http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/`, which is itself
3. Request for `/mycontext/` arrives at your virtual host
4. `ProxyPass` reverse proxies it to `http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/mycontext/`
5. Request for `/mycontext/mycontest/` arrives at your virtual host
6. `ProxyPass` reverse proxies it to `http://www.yyy.com/mycontext/mycontext/mycontext/`

etc.

I think what you're probably looking for is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mycontext/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mycontext/$1 [L]
```

But this has nothing to do with your load balancer or your tomcat server.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon.  That's it!.  I was struggling with the syntax.